# How to highlight or mark a node in a treeView in C #?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeView in a parent form which has several nodes, when clicking on the nodes, they call several form children.

It's also possible that from a child form, another child form is called, and this works very well.

The problem is that the node that corresponds to the new child form, is not pointed or marked because it only happens when you click on the node with the mouse.

It is for this reason that I want to know how to mark or indicate a node by programming.

I have tried the following:

```
  TreeNode CategoryNode;
  CategoryNode = myTreeView.Nodes[3];
  myTreeView.Focus();
  myTreeView.SelectedNode = CategoryNode;
```

And it works similar to clicking on the node and the corresponding form is called, but the node is still not marked or highlighted, as I said before it only works by clicking the mouse on the node.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Windows Forms, WPF or something else?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms

Comment: `HideSelection = false`